# Installation of Dynamic AX 2012 : 'The model store schema was not found in the database MicrosoftDynamicsAXBaseline'

Tags: sql-server-2012, axapta, x++

When Installing Dynamic AX 2012 Trial Version on my Local System, It shows me an error in Log File : 
'**The model store schema was not found in the database MicrosoftDynamicsAXBaseline.**'

Downloaded Free Trial Version from : http://getintopc.com/softwares/erp-systems/microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012-free-download/

Local System Configuration :

- Windows 7 Professional 64 bit
- RAM : 8 GB
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

You have to [`Initialize-AXModelStore`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj720267.aspx).

```
Initialize-AXModelStore -Database MicrosoftDynamicsAXBaseline
```

Comment: Not able to execute this command in Windows Powershell. . . .Can you help me, please ?

Comment: The command he gave is for the "Dynamics PowerShell".  If you can't find it, you can use axutil alternatively. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh456294.aspx

Comment: Administrative Tools - Microsoft Dynamics AX Management Shell.